# If with or statement does not work - javascript

Tags: javascript

In my app this validation check works for one condition and not working if I want to check it for 2 conditions:

```
if (!admin.isMemberOf('group2')) {...} //works

if (!admin.isMemberOf('group1') || !admin.isMemberOf('group2')) {...} // not working
```

In order to do check for any of these I can simply use `||` but It returns false for both groups. How to use it right in this case? Thank you.

edit: full condition

```
   if (!req.user.roles.admin.isMemberOf('root2') || !req.user.roles.admin.isMemberOf('admins2')) {
     workflow.outcome.errors.push('You may not create account groups.');
     return workflow.emit('response');
   }
```

**edit2**
I know the question sounded silly but I was trying to do it straightforward as according to what i needed - prevent some action, if the member is member of all groups, except the pointed one (or several) groups. of course it can be replaced with "not this and other group"

Comment: Do you know what `||` mean?

Comment: So what do you want to happen, go in if they are not a member of both things or not a member of one of them?

Comment: I need to prevent some action, if the member is member of all groups, except the pointed one (or several) groups. Alon Eitan - yes i do know what || means.

Answer (score 3):

You need a logical AND `&&`, because the condition with OR is always `true`.

```
if (!admin.isMemberOf('group1') && !admin.isMemberOf('group2')) {...}
```